# Showing the original index of an element in a vector after bubblesort

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to c++ and i'm having a problem with my code. I need to show the original indexes of a vector before it was sorted, after sorted. I tried it like this:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void bubblesort(vector<int> &a, int n) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = n - 1; i > j; i--) {
            if (a.at(i) < a.at(i-1)) {
                int aux = a.at(i);
                a.at(i) = a.at(i-1);
                a.at(i-1) = aux;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Digite o tamanho do vetor: ";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> vold;
    vector<int> pos;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        v.push_back(a);
        vold.push_back(a);
    }

    bubblesort(v, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (vold.at(i) == v.at(i)) {
            pos.push_back(i);
        }
        else {
            for (int j = i+1; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (vold.at(i) == v.at(j)) {
                    pos.at(j) = i;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }

    for (const int& i : pos) {
        cout << i << "  ";
    }

    

    system("pause>0");
}
```

But it didn't worked, if someone could help me to see what I'm doing wrong I would be glad, thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have will fail if there are duplicates. Can you afford to use a `vector` of `pair`s? The first item in the `pair` is the integer you want sorted and the other value is the initial position. When you sort the pairs by the first value, the index value goes with it.

Comment: Don't sort the vector, sort an index vector based on the original vector.  Maybe that's the "trick" that you're missing.  You also don't need to pass `n` as an argument, since a vector already knows how many elements there are using the `size()` member function.  Introducing extraneous variables for no reason just opens you up for bugs to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to show the indices of the sorted vector, then another approach is to not sort the original vector, but instead to sort a vector of index values based on the original vector.

The index vector would be initialized to 0, 1, 2, etc. up until the vector's size, minus 1.

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

void bubblesort(std::vector<int> &a, std::vector<int>& index) 
{
    // Make sure the index vector is the same size as
    // the original
    index.resize(a.size());

    if ( a.size() <= 1 )
       return;

    // This is just a shortcut way of setting the values to 0,1,2,etc.
    std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    size_t n = a.size();

    // Here is your sort, but with one difference...
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) 
    {
        for (size_t i = n - 1; i > j; i--) 
        {
            // Look at the comparison being done here using the index array
            if (a.at(index[i]) < a.at(index[i-1])) 
            {
                 // We swap the index values, not the values
                 // in the vector
                 int aux = index.at(i);
                 index.at(i) = index.at(i-1);
                 index.at(i-1) = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {3, 1, 65, 23, 4};
    std::vector<int> index;
    bubblesort(v, index);

    // Display the index values of the sorted items     
    for (const int& i : index) 
        std::cout << i << "  ";
}
```

Output:

```
1  0  4  3  2
```

Note that the `bubblesort` function takes a vector of indices, and not `n`.  There is no need to pass `n`, since a vector already knows its own size by utilizing the `size()` function.

The output shows the original index of each of the sorted items.

Comment: Is there a reason not using `std::swap(index.at(i), index.at(i-1))`? Like you demonstrate element accessing by `at()` instead of `[]`. I agree that `at()`  doing boundary check would help user who didn't notice it.

Comment: I could have used `std::swap`, but the goal was to show the OP the minor difference between this code and their current non-working code.